# Set layout_column and layout_row in GridLayout programmatically

Tags: android, android-xml, android-gridlayout

I have a GridLayout (not GridView) where I want to add some views with a special row and column inex. In XML I can set the View with:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_row="4"
    android:text="Large Text" />
```

But how can I set the attributes `layout_column` and `layout_row` programmatically? I want something like this:

```
GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(getActivity());

grid.setColumn(2);
grid.setRow(4);

grid.addView(new Button(getActivity());
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The equivalent of `layout_column` and `layout_row`, as with all `layout_...` parameters, is to be found as a parameter of a subclass of `LayoutParams`.

In this case it's `GridLayout.LayoutParams`, and we use it like this (for a 2x2 grid with a subview in the final row and column, centred within the cell):

```
gridLayout.setColumnCount(2);
gridLayout.setRowCount(2);

gridLayout.addView(subview, new GridLayout.LayoutParams(
                              GridLayout.spec(1, GridLayout.CENTER),
                              GridLayout.spec(1, GridLayout.CENTER)));
```

Comment: And how would I move a view to let's say (0,0)?

Comment: Well wouldn't it just be `GridLayout.spec(0, GridLayout.CENTER)`? Also kudos for sticking to one question for almost a year and a half!