# How can I set the column and row of a child of GridLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I set the column and row of a child of GridLayout in a .java file and not using xml?

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
GridLayout gl = new GridLayout(context);
GridLayout.LayoutParams glp = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();

gl.setMinimumHeight(200);
gl.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
gl.setRowCount(1);
gl.setColumnCount(1);


ImageView left = new ImageView(context);
ImageView right = new ImageView(context);

//I want these two items to be on the same row. 
gl.addView(left);
gl.addView(right);
```

This seams to have the answer
[Set layout_column and layout_row in GridLayout programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16640142/set-layout-column-and-layout-row-in-gridlayout-programmatically)
Well it doesn't seam to work but it is the type of answer I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the GridLayout two columns.
You add them in a row, so you have to provide 2 columns when you want to have 2 items in 1 row.

So just do:

```
gl.setColumnCount(2);
```

and then

```
gl.addView(left);
gl.addView(right);
```