# How can I set a row and a column programatically for a view in a GridLayout?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a GridLayout and I am adding a new view into it like this

```
myGridLayout.AddView(myView);
```

The problem is, that I can't figure out how to set the column and row for it via code.
In axml it would look like this:

```
       <TextView
            android:layout_row="5"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:text="Test"
  />
```

How can I set the "android:layout_row" and "android:layout_column" in code?

*(This is for xamarin android NOT for xamarin forms)*

This is not a duplicate of [Set layout_column and layout_row in GridLayout programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16640142/set-layout-column-and-layout-row-in-gridlayout-programmatically) I already tried that solution and it is not working, since GridLayout.spec does not exist and GridLayout.Spec is not accessible.